# pattern-avoiding permutations vs multi-core partitions

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, permutations, enumerative-combinatorics

Let $\mathfrak{S}_n$ be the permutation group on $[n]$. Given the pattern $\sigma=k(k-1)\cdots321$, let $I_n(\sigma)$ be the number of [**involutions**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationInvolution.html) in $\mathfrak{S}_n$ that [avoid the pattern $\sigma$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerations_of_specific_permutation_classes). Amitai Regev proved ([see this paper and references therein](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669889800344)) the case $k=4$:
$$I_n((4321))=\sum_{k\geq0}\binom{n}{2k}C_k$$
which are the Motzkin numbers. Here $C_k$ are the Catalan numbers.

Given an integer partition $\lambda$, draw the Young diagram and fill in hook-lengths of each cell. If a number $t$ is not among these hook-lengths then $\lambda$ is called a $t$-core. If it misses $a, b, c$ then call it an $(a,b,c)$-core partition.

Let $N(n,n+1,n+2)$ be the number of all partitions that are $(n,n+1,n+2)$-core partitions. Then ([see this paper for definitions and this result](https://www.math.temple.edu/~tewodros/multicores.pdf))
$$N(n,n+1,n+2)=\sum_{k\geq0}\binom{n}{2k}C_k.$$

> **QUESTION.** Is there a direct bijection between the above $(4321)$-avoiding involutions in $\mathfrak{S}_n$ and $(n,n+1,n+2)$-core partitions?

**EDIT.** Fedor's comment/question below alerted me to correct a mistake: we are only counting [involutions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationInvolution.html) and not all permutations.

Comment: I find it reasonable to reproduce the definiton of $S$-core here.

Comment: I edited to account for this, hope it helps.

Comment: Hm, what are six diagrams without hook lengths 3,4,5?

Comment: Well, empty diagram and three diagrams with 1 or 2 boxes, what else?

Comment: @Fedor: Well, the Motzkin numbers for $n\geq0$ are: $1, 1, 2, 4, 9, 21, 51, 127,\dots$. So, corresponding to $(3,4,5)$, there are $4$ core partitions. Where did you get $6$?

Comment: All six permutations of 123 avoid 4321, right?

Comment: Oh my! I missed out something, inadvertently. I was meaning to say "all involutions" and not "all permutations". So sorry.